# How to store my docker registry in the file system

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to setup a private registry behind a nginx server. To do that I configured nginx with a basic auth and started a docker container like this:

```
docker run -d \
     -e STANDALONE=true \
     -e INDEX_ENDPOINT=https://docker.example.com \
     -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=local \
     -e STORAGE_PATH=/home/example/registry \
     -p 5000:5000 \
     registry
```

By doing that, I can login to my registry, push/pull images... But if I stop the container and start it again, everything is lost. I would have expected my registry to be save in `/home/example/registry` but this is not the case. Can someone tell me what I missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would have expected my registry to be save in /home/example/registry but this is not the case

it is the case, only the `/home/exemple/registry` directory is on the docker container file system, not the docker host file system.

If you run your container mounting one of your docker host directory to a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) in the container, it would achieve what you want:

```
docker run -d \
     -e STANDALONE=true \
     -e INDEX_ENDPOINT=https://docker.example.com \
     -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=local \
     -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry \
     -p 5000:5000 \
     -v /home/example/registry:/registry \
     registry
```

just make sure that `/home/example/registry` exists on the docker host side.